# subset dataset into 2 smaller ones

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

How can I subset the following dataset based on the fact that `Numeric_variable` includes 2 for some units (e.g. A), and 3 for some other units (e.g. B)?

```
Unit | Numeric_variable
A    | 1
A    | 1
A    | 2
A    | 2
A    | 2
A    | 2
C    | 1
C    | 1
C    | 2
C    | 2
C    | 2
C    | 2
B    | 1
B    | 1
B    | 3
B    | 3
B    | 3
B    | 3
D    | 1
D    | 1
D    | 3
D    | 3
D    | 3
D    | 3
```

Into:

df1:

```
Unit | Numeric_variable
A    | 1
A    | 1
A    | 2
A    | 2
A    | 2
A    | 2
C    | 1
C    | 1
C    | 2
C    | 2
C    | 2
C    | 2
```

df2:

```
Unit | Numeric_variable
B    | 1
B    | 1
B    | 3
B    | 3
B    | 3
B    | 3
D    | 1
D    | 1
D    | 3
D    | 3
D    | 3
D    | 3
```

By doing `df1 <- df[which(df$Numeric_variable != 3),]`, I obtain the below which is not what I would like to get. I would like to get the above df1.

```
Unit | Numeric_variable
A    | 1
A    | 1
A    | 2
A    | 2
A    | 2
A    | 2
B    | 1
B    | 1
D    | 1
D    | 1
```

Comment: use `split(df, df$Unit)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, that does not work unfortunately because it creates a list, I have many Units and other variables in my dataset. I need to play with values of Numeric_variable, and I don't understand why the which command is not working as I thought it should.

Comment: It is not recommended to create multiple objects in the global env.  But if you insist from the `list`, you can use `list2env` to create objects i.e. `lst1 <- split(df, df$Unit); list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_all <- df %>% 
  mutate(x = case_when(Numeric_variable==2 ~ 2,
                       Numeric_variable==3 ~ 3,
                       TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>% 
  fill(x, .direction = "up") 

df_2 <- df_all %>% 
  filter(x == 2) %>% 
  select(-x)

df_3 <- df_all %>% 
  filter(x == 3) %>% 
  select(-x)
```

```
> df_2
   Unit Numeric_variable
1     A                1
2     A                1
3     A                2
4     A                2
5     A                2
6     A                2
7     C                1
8     C                1
9     C                2
10    C                2
11    C                2
12    C                2
> df_3
   Unit Numeric_variable
1     B                1
2     B                1
3     B                3
4     B                3
5     B                3
6     B                3
7     D                1
8     D                1
9     D                3
10    D                3
11    D                3
12    D                3
```

Comment: Thanks @TarJae, this solution is difficult in my context because I have multiple Units that should be split based on the fact that Numeric_variable includes 2 for some units and 3 for some other units

Comment: sorry I have some units let's say E with only 1,1,1,1,1,1 - I would like to keep them as well in each group, is it easy to adapt your solution for this?

Comment: This should be no problem. Could you please open a new question with the new dataframe and the expected output. One more tip: Learn about `dput()` function, presenting your data as dput output increases the chance to get adequate help!

Comment: Thanks TarJae. I have added a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73057508/subset-dataset-into-2-smaller-ones-while-keeping-common-units and included code to generate data

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split` from `base R`

```
grp <- (with(df, match(Unit, unique(Unit)))-1) %/% 2 + 1
lst1 <- split(df, grp)
names(lst1) <- paste0("df", seq_along(lst1))
```

and then create objects in the global env from the `list` elements with `list2env`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Now, check for 'df1' and 'df2' in the global env

```
> df1
   Unit Numeric_variable
1     A                1
2     A                1
3     A                2
4     A                2
5     A                2
6     A                2
7     C                1
8     C                1
9     C                2
10    C                2
11    C                2
12    C                2
> df2
   Unit Numeric_variable
13    B                1
14    B                1
15    B                3
16    B                3
17    B                3
18    B                3
19    D                1
20    D                1
21    D                3
22    D                3
23    D                3
24    D                3
```

---

If it needs at least one 2 and one 3, then `subset` the data for 2, 3, create a new column 'grp' and then `split` after `merge`ing

```
tmp <- merge(df, transform(unique(subset(df, 
   Numeric_variable %in% 
   2:3)), grp = as.integer(factor(Numeric_variable)))[-2],
     all.x = TRUE, by = 'Unit')
lst1 <- split(tmp[-3], tmp$grp)
names(lst1) <- paste0("df", seq_along(lst1))
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Unit = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D"), Numeric_variable = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, this does not work unfortunately as mentioned above

Comment: I have multiple Units that should be split based on the fact that Numeric_variable includes 2 for some units and 3 for some other units, I do not want to split all Units in my sample, does this make sense? I want to end up with 2 groups, not multiple groups (like one per Unit). Thanks

Comment: Yes thanks, I have just done it.